# Why does hasOwnProperty not recognise functions on an object's prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, hasownproperty

I understand that the `hasOwnProperty` method in JavaScript exists to identify properties only of the current type, but there is something in the prototype chain here that is confusing to me.

Let us imagine that I define a type called Bob, and assign two child functions to my Bob type in two different ways:

```
function Bob()
{
    this.name="Bob"; 
    this.sayGoodbye=function()
    {
        console.log("goodbye");   
    }
}

Bob.prototype.sayHello= function()
{
    console.log("hello");   
}
```

Now aside from having access to closure scope in the case of `sayGoodbye`, it seems to me that both functions belonging to the `Bob` class should be more or less equal. However, when I look for them with `hasOwnProperty` they are not the same as far as JavaScript is concerned:

```
var myBob = new Bob();
console.log( myBob.name ); // Bob, obviously 
console.log( myBob.hasOwnProperty("sayHello"));  // false
console.log( myBob.hasOwnProperty("sayGoodbye")); // true
console.log( "sayHello" in myBob ); // true
```

What is happening here in terms of scope? I could not create an instance of the `Bob` type without having the `sayHello()` and `sayGoodbye()` properties connected to it, so why is the prototype method a second class citizen as far as `hasOwnProperty` is concerned? Is `Bob.prototype` a type that exists somehow independently of the `Bob` type, from which `Bob` inherits everything?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` exists only to check the object itself for properties, it explicitly does not walk up the prototype chain, as that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: What I was looking for clarification on is why properties on a type's own prototype would not be identified by `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Property access has nothing to do with scope, it is entirely different.

Comment: @glenatron - The real answer is because that's the way `hasOwnProperty()` was designed.  It only checks properties directly on the object, not anywhere in the prototype chain.  I can see a rationale for a different function that tells you if the property is on the object or in it's own prototype, but that is not what `.hasOwnProperty()` was written to do.  You could write such a function.

Comment: @jfriend00— *typeof* will suite for most cases, but if traversing the `[[Prototype]]` chain is required, then it is dependent on one of [`getPrototyeOf`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2), `__proto__` or that the *constructor* property and *constructor.prototoype* are accurate. But I don't see that there's much benefit to that beyond that provided by *typeof*.

Comment: @RobG - it depends upon what the OP is really trying to do.  My guess is that there's probably a better way to solve their issue entirely if they explained what the actual problem is.

Comment: @jfriend00 my exact goal here is to improve my understanding of how JavaScript's scope and inheritance stuff works, which still manages to be a regular source of surprises to me after all these years.

Comment: @glenatron—step one is recognising that scope has nothing to do with property access. The first relates to resolution of variables in a [lexical environment](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2), the other relates to [property name](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.30) resolution on an object and its `[[Prototype]]` chain.

Comment: @glenatron - The reason I asked about the actual problem is that I've encountered many reasons to use `.hasOwnProperty()` the way it works and many reasons to see if the object has a property in any way, but never encountered a reason to use the function you're asking about in real code.

Comment: @jfriend00 The structure of the actual case isn't too different to my example- I have classes that have a set of properties, some of which are 'own' properties others are on the class prototype ( but no higher up the chain ) and as both seem to me ( with a background in more traditional object oriented languages ) to be part of the same class definition, I wasn't sure why I could only treat some as properties of an instance of the type. As it is I am just using `in` to do the same job, which is fine here. Trying to understand rather than just fix the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're confusing a few concepts here. Let's take this quote from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> Every object descended from `Object` inherits the `hasOwnProperty` method.
>   This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a **direct property** of that object; unlike the `in`
>   operator, this method **does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain**.

So that's the key here. When you use `new` JavaScript will assign a brand new object to `this` and return it, that's what an instance is. Any property declared inside the constructor is an **own property**. Properties declared on the `prototype` are not, since they are shared with other instances of the same object.

And a `prototype` is also an `Object`, for example:

```
Bob.prototype.hasOwnProperty("sayHello"); //=> true

myBob.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("sayHello"); //=> true
```

Comment: Does that mean I could instantiate a new `Bob.prototype` that would have access to all the shared properties of the `Bob` type but not its constructor? Assuming I was sufficiently drunk that it seemed like a good idea.

Comment: Yes, that how you do inheritance, `NewObject.prototype = Object.create(Bob.prototype)`

Comment: @glenatron - `Bob.prototype` already exists as an object.  You don't have to instantiate one to read what's in it.

Comment: @elclanrs that's not how _I_ do inheritance, but it is very probably how I _should_ do inheritance. Normally I'd just say `James.prototype = new Bob()`

Comment: Well, yes that's how you'd do it in old browsers, but it's a bit hacky in a way... Check the polyfill here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that the hasOwnProperty method in JavaScript exists to identify properties only of the current type

That is not correct. [*hasOwnProperty*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5) identifies **own** properties of an object, that is, properties of the object itself. It does not consider inherited properties on an object's `[[Prototype]]` chain.

e.g.

```
var foo = {name: 'foo'};

// Check for an own property
foo.hasOwnProperty('name'); // true
```

The object *foo* also inherits a *toString* method from Object.prototype, but it's not an "own" property:

```
typeof foo.toString             // function
foo.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false
```

Comment: I got that regarding the longer inheritance chain. The specific confusion I had was where one had a property declared through the `foo.prototype.name` specifically, so the property only exists on type `foo` and it's children. Although the definition of _own_ properties explains where I went wrong, I don't think it would be illogical if all properties uniquely belonging to `foo` and its children were considered properties of `foo` rather than only those within the function declaration.